# When A was half B's age, B was one fourth A's age.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The question goes like this :

A told B, "*When I was half your present age, you were one -fourth my present age*". If A is currently 60 yrs, how old is B ?

I am unable to form equations for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $b$ be the age of B now.  One fourth A's present age is $15$.  A was half B's present age $60-b/2$ years ago.  B's age then was $b-(60-b/2)$, so $b-(60-b/2)=15$

Comment: Answer is 50, by the book.

Comment: @ultimate Did you bother to even read his post?

Comment: I did but it didn't match the answer so I am asking to explain.

Comment: Yes, if you solve the equation you get $b=50$.  I left that for you. Maybe you dropped a sign in solving.

Comment: Yeah, true. Thank you !